# Symfony last accessed entitys

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity

I am working on a symfony project, which contains users and projects. I would like to get the 5 last accesed project for a single user.

I could do this by just adding a service, and when a certain route is hit, update a many-to-many relationship between the project and user entity. But I would like to ask if someone knows of a better solution.

Comment: it's the right way, just use kernel listener to decouple it

Comment: I know and understand listeners, but can you elaborate on the kernel listener ?

Comment: elaborate what? can i flush data on a listener? yes of course

Comment: you would do a listener with onKernelRequest -> if (!$event == some path) {
            //add an entry to the last accesed table
            return;
        }

Am I correct ?

Comment: Yep only I would list to KernelEvents::CONTROLLER just to ensure that the security listener was called first.

Comment: Use redis you will save some queries.